# TextLabel returning a null for prefilled text

Tags: swift, null, textlabel

I'm using Swiftforms, found [here](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms), to add a form to fill out for the user. Since I already have most of the information I'm filling out the form for the user and then they are able to edit it if they choose and click submit. When I prefilled the text, the results are coming back null for the information I filled in, in this case the email address.

```
 var row: FormRowDescriptor! = FormRowDescriptor(tag: Static.emailTag, rowType: .Email, title: "Email")
    row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.CellConfiguration] = ["textField.text" : "john@gmail.com", "textField.textAlignment" : NSTextAlignment.Right.rawValue]
    section1.addRow(row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I have to set the `row.value = ""`